# Did Agnes move to Westview before or after the town was transformed?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

Within the show, *WandaVision*, Agnes shows up early on as a nosy neighbor who threatens the reveal of Wanda and Vision's true natures, but is otherwise a quirky ally. Episodes 7 and 8 reveal her true nature, namely that

> She's Agatha Harkness, a witch from the Salem, who has been manipulating Wanda in an effort to learn where she got the power for such a massive transformation, and it was Agatha all along.

That's reasonable enough, except that what we're shown seems to indicate that Agnes was there before the transformation of the town. I haven't had a chance to rewatch the episodes for further clues (and the new baby means I kept missing bits of what was going on), and what I've found online hasn't helped elucidate, but was Agnes in the neighborhood prior to things transforming? If so, was it because she knew something was going to happen, or just that she was in the right place at the right time?

Comment: +1 for the use of "elucidate"!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

She came after, when she reveals herself to Wanda she specifically mentions she sensed the place and then came over.

> **Agatha:** Oh, Wanda, oh, when I sensed this place, the afterglow of so many spells cast all at once... Oh, I couldn’t make heads or tails of it.
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 8, "Previously On"</sub>

On top of that in episode 7, "Breaking the Fourth Wall", in "Agatha All Along" we see Agatha enter Westview and she transforms herself into black and white with the appropriate attire.

Comment: There's also the hint in Ep 1 already when she says she was out of town and just came back.

Comment: @ths Good call _"Forgive me for not stopping by sooner to welcome you to the block. My mother-in-law was in town, so I wasn't."_ I'll leave it out of the answer because I don't think it's necessary but it's good back up evidence.

Comment: There's also a hint in one of the scenes from the outside where they try to assign the characters from the show to real people - and Agnes is there, the only one on the board who doesn't have an ID card.

Comment: @Luaan Aye, I mention that in this [somewhat related answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/243517/58193) of mine.

Comment: I'm still not 100% since the song where she shows up, a few of the scenes are subtly different from the other angle whether it's reshots, unreliable narrator, or evidence of her manipulations, but overall, this holds up.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots There is certainly an element of unreliable narrator in the song, mostly to wind Wanda up. However, a lot of what she does is out of the shot the first time round. For example, we don't see the front garden when Fietro turns up so can't tell if Agatha is on the grass or not.